# My IF/ELSE IF Statement is not working in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble implementing the following if statement into my code:

```
IF(O3<0,"Y",N")
```

Can someone help alter my code to include this if statement? Here is what I've tried:

```
  If Range("O3:O4183") < 0 Then Range("P3").Value = "Y"
    Worksheets("Sample File").Range("P3:P4183").FillDown

    ElseIf Range("O3:O4183") > 0 Then Range("P3").Value = "N"
            Worksheets("Sample File").Range("P3:P4183").FillDown

            End If
```

Full code:

```
Sub stackoverflow()

Dim rng As Range

''sample file creation
''values

        Range("A3").Value = "CSH"   ''hardcode
        Worksheets("Sample File").Range("A3:A4183").FillDown

        Set rng = Worksheets("File").Range("C2:C4182")
        Worksheets("Sample File").Range("B3").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

                Set rng = Worksheets("File").Range("D2:D4182")
        Worksheets("Sample File").Range("C3").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

         Range("D3").Value = "1"   ''hardcode
        Worksheets("Sample File").Range("D3:D4183").FillDown

                Set rng = Worksheets("File").Range("E2:E4182")
        Worksheets("Sample File").Range("E3").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

                Set rng = Worksheets("File").Range("E2:E4182")
        Worksheets("Sample File").Range("F3").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

         Range("G3").Value = "USD"   ''hardcode
        Worksheets("Sample File").Range("G3:G4183").FillDown

              Set rng = Worksheets("File").Range("K2:K4182")
        Worksheets("Sample File").Range("H3").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

                      Set rng = Worksheets("File").Range("F2:F4182")
        Worksheets("Sample File").Range("I3").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

         Range("J3").Value = "DEALT"   ''hardcode
        Worksheets("Sample File").Range("J3:J4183").FillDown

                      Set rng = Worksheets("File").Range("H2:H4182")
        Worksheets("Sample File").Range("M3").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

         Range("N3").Value = "0"   ''hardcode
        Worksheets("Sample File").Range("N3:N4183").FillDown

                     Set rng = Worksheets("File").Range("J2:J4182")
        Worksheets("Sample File").Range("O3").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

        ''If statement:  IF(O3<0,"Y",N")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try

```
Option Explicit
'

Sub stackoverflow()

    Dim src As Range
    Set src = Worksheets("File").Range("2:4182")

    Dim dst As Range
    Set dst = Worksheets("Sample File").Range("3:4183")

    ' sample file creation
    ' values

    dst.Columns("A") = "CSH"   ' hardcode
    dst.Columns("D") = "1"
    dst.Columns("G") = "USD"
    dst.Columns("J") = "DEALT"
    dst.Columns("N") = "0"

    dst.Columns("B") = src.Columns("C").Value
    dst.Columns("C") = src.Columns("D").Value
    dst.Columns("E") = src.Columns("E").Value
    dst.Columns("F") = src.Columns("E").Value
    dst.Columns("H") = src.Columns("K").Value
    dst.Columns("I") = src.Columns("F").Value
    dst.Columns("M") = src.Columns("H").Value
    dst.Columns("O") = src.Columns("J").Value

    dst.Columns("P") = "=IF(RC[-1]<0,""Y"",""N"")"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 valid syntaxes for an `If` statement in VBA.

### Statement Syntax

```
If {bool-expression} Then {statement}
```

That's what you have here:

```
If Range("O3:O4183") < 0 Then Range("P3").Value = "Y"
    Worksheets("Sample File").Range("P3:P4183").FillDown
```

The indentation is misleading - the 2nd line will execute unconditionally, regardless of the outcome of the `{bool-expression}` in the `If` statement.

### Block Syntax

```
If {bool-expression} Then
    {statements}
[ElseIf {bool-expression} Then]
    {statements}
[Else]
    {statements}
End If
```

Use that syntax when you want `Else`/`ElseIf` logic, or if you want to execute more than 1 statement conditionally*.

*there *are* ways to execute multiple statements conditionally using the *statement syntax*, but they're detrimental to readability; stay away from easy bugs, prefer the block syntax.

Answer (score 1):

was able to come up with this,

```
 Set range1 = Worksheets("Sample File").Range("P3:P4183")
    range1.Cells.Value = "=IF(RC[-1]<0,""Y"",""N"")"
    Worksheets("Sample File").Range("P3:P4183").FillDown
```

Seems to work.